# Flutter iOS app size increase without changes asset/lbrary

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have my own game in Flutter. I am wondering after seeing size of my current iOS app. I didn't change anything not even asset/library etc. I just want to upload new version of app after just change few lines of code.

Current version of iOS app on App Store. (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/morude-frrr-fly-or-not/id1482474790)

## Size : 79.7 MB

Updated version of APP

## Size : 180. MB +

I checked by different Apps. same issue occur, size of iOS app found more than 180 MB. What happened I don't know.  Need to change any settings at my end? let me know if any info. require at my end.

> **Result of flutter doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale
    en-IN)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps with your question:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47101#issuecomment-567522077